# jquery animate appending to div

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I have a grid, and I want to show an element sliding through them; for example:

```
<div id="zone-1" class="lab-zone lab-left-column">
    <div id="user">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="zone-2" class="lab-zone lab-left-column">
</div>
<div id="zone-3" class="lab-zone lab-center-column">
</div>
<div id="zone-4" class="lab-zone lab-center-column">
</div>
<div id="zone-5" class="lab-zone lab-right-column">
</div>
<div id="zone-6" class="lab-zone lab-right-column">
</div>
```

the `user` div has a fill effect and I want to animate the movement of it to another `zone-x` div. Could I do this with a `slide<direction>` jquery event or is there another way I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKING DEMO:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcDyT/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".lab-zone ").click(function () {
    $('#user').css("background-color", "lightblue");
    move = $(this).position();
    $('#user').animate({
        top: move.top,
        left: move.left

    });

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do like slide on div(.lab-zone) click, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vDvUn/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lab-zone").click(function(){
        position = $(this).position();
        $('#user').animate({
           top: position.top,
            left:position.left
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with some animation too :)

http://jsfiddle.net/tLttL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".lab-zone ").click(function () {
    change = $(this).position();
    $('#user').animate({
        top: change.top,
        left: change.left
   });
});
```

});